# How to sort Export options lists in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.2

I have to sort Export options in Magento 2 UI admin report grid. I have to keep Excel option in first then CSV option and remove the Excel XML option.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">braintree_report.braintree_report_data_source</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <spinner>braintree_report_columns</spinner>
        <deps>
            <dep>braintree_report.braintree_report_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="braintree_report_data_source">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Braintree/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <updateUrl path="mui/index/render"/>
        </settings>
        <aclResource>Magento_Braintree::settlement_report</aclResource>
        <dataProvider class="BraintreeTransactionsDataProvider" name="braintree_report_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>page_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    <container name="listing_top" template="ui/grid/toolbar">
        <container name="bookmarks" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/bookmarks/bookmarks" displayArea="dataGridActions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">localStorage</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </container>
        <container name="columns_controls" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns" displayArea="dataGridActions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">braintree_report.braintree_report.braintree_report_columns</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </container>
        <exportButton name="export_button"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters" displayArea="dataGridFilters">
            <settings>
                <dataScope>filters</dataScope>
                <childDefaults>
                    <param name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">braintree_report.braintree_report.listing_top.bookmarks:current.columns.${ $.index }.visible</item>
                    </param>
                    <param name="provider" xsi:type="string">braintree_report.braintree_report.listing_top.listing_filters</param>
                </childDefaults>
                <storageConfig>
                    <namespace>current.filters</namespace>
                    <provider>braintree_report.braintree_report.listing_top.bookmarks</provider>
                </storageConfig>
            </settings>
            <filterSelect name="status" provider="${ $.parentName }">
                <settings>
                    <options class="Magento\Braintree\Ui\Component\Report\Listing\Column\Status"/>
                    <caption translate="true">Select...</caption>
                    <label translate="true">Status</label>
                    <dataScope>status</dataScope>
                    <imports>
                        <link name="visible">componentType = column, index = ${ $.index }:visible</link>
                    </imports>
                </settings>
            </filterSelect>
            <filterSelect name="type" provider="${ $.parentName }">
                <settings>
                    <options class="Magento\Braintree\Ui\Component\Report\Listing\Column\TransactionType"/>
                    <caption translate="true">Select...</caption>
                    <label translate="true">Transaction Type</label>
                    <dataScope>type</dataScope>
                    <imports>
                        <link name="visible">componentType = column, index = ${ $.index }:visible</link>
                    </imports>
                </settings>
            </filterSelect>
            <filterSelect name="paymentInstrumentType" provider="${ $.parentName }">
                <settings>
                    <options class="Magento\Braintree\Ui\Component\Report\Listing\Column\PaymentType"/>
                    <caption translate="true">Select...</caption>
                    <label translate="true">Payment Type</label>
                    <dataScope>paymentInstrumentType</dataScope>
                    <imports>
                        <link name="visible">componentType = column, index = ${ $.index }:visible</link>
                    </imports>
                </settings>
            </filterSelect>
            <filterInput name="paypalDetails_paymentId">
                <settings>
                    <label translate="true">PayPal Payment ID</label>
                    <dataScope>paypalDetails_paymentId</dataScope>
                </settings>
            </filterInput>
            <filterRange name="createdAt" class="Magento\Braintree\Ui\Component\Report\Filters\Type\DateRange" provider="${ $.parentName }" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/filters/range" template="ui/grid/filters/elements/group">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="parent" xsi:type="string">braintree_report.braintree_report.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <settings>
                    <rangeType>date</rangeType>
                    <label translate="true">Created At</label>
                    <dataScope>createdAt</dataScope>
                    <imports>
                        <link name="visible">componentType = column, index = ${ $.index }:visible</link>
                    </imports>
                </settings>
            </filterRange>
        </filters>
    </container>
    <columns name="braintree_report_columns">
        <settings>
            <childDefaults>
                <param name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">braintree_report.braintree_report.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                </param>
                <param name="controlVisibility" xsi:type="boolean">true</param>
                <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">braintree_report.braintree_report.braintree_report_columns_editor</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </param>
            </childDefaults>
            <storageConfig>
                <namespace>current</namespace>
                <provider>braintree_report.braintree_report.listing_top.bookmarks</provider>
            </storageConfig>
        </settings>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <settings>
                <indexField>id</indexField>
            </settings>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="id">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Transaction ID</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="orderId">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Order ID</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="paypalDetails_paymentId">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">PayPal Payment ID</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="paymentInstrumentType">
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Payment Type</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="type">
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Type</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="createdAt" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date">
            <settings>
                <dataType>date</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Created At</label>
                <sorting>desc</sorting>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="amount" class="Magento\Sales\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Price">
            <settings>
                <filter>textRange</filter>
                <label translate="true">Amount</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="processorSettlementResponseCode">
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Settlement Code</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="status">
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Status</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="processorSettlementResponseText">
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Settlement Response Text</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="refundIds">
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Refund Ids</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="merchantAccountId">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Merchant Account ID</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="settlementBatchId">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">Settlement Batch ID</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
        <column name="currencyIsoCode">
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Currency</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Comment: custom grid ???

Comment: @RkRathod it Magento default UI grid.

Comment: specify which grid ???

Comment: @RkRathod Braintree Settlement Report

Comment: please attach your grid code

Comment: @RkRathod You mean to say UI component?

Comment: yes.............

Comment: @RkRathod updated question.